# Bash-parsing string into an array of floating point numbers

Tags: bash, parsing

I wish to create an array of floating point numbers (called b) in BASH, the contents of the array is given by parsing the following variable `adse`:

```
echo $adse
16.92 18.29 19.18 20.87 2.78 2.88 2.77 2.83 2.80 2.78 2.73 2.73 2.75 2.93 2.91 2.93 2.77 4.64 2.67 3.01 6.78
```

so that b[1]=16.92; b[2]=18.29.....

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With

```
b=($adse)
```

you get a bash array `b`. Individual arguments can be accessed with `${b[index]}`. Indices are zero-based, so the first element is `${b[0]}`.

Be aware that you will find it difficult to do anything with these values in bash, though. It might be a good idea to use a scripting language that has support for floating point calculations, such as Perl or Python.

For a more in-depth discussion of bash arrays, see [this link](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html).

Comment: Important to note that bash arrays are zero-indexed, so `${b[0]}` is `16.92`

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks, I didn't notice OP assumed one-based indices. I edited it in.

Comment: If `$adse` includes a `*`, this could be problematic. If you're sure it is just numbers, it's a nice solution.

Answer (score 4):

The canonical solution is:

```
read -r -d '' -a b <<<"$adse"
```

Unlike solutions which rely on default word-splitting of an unquoted expansion of `$adse`, the `read` built-in will not produce unwanted expansions of glob characters.

If you want to split the variable on some character other than whitespace, you can set `IFS` locally for the `read`:

```
IFS=: read -r -d '' -a b <<<"$adse"
```

That will not split on newlines. If you wanted to split on colon or newline, you could use `IFS=$':\n'`.

Both of the above will set `b[0]` to the first element, not `b[1]`. If you wanted to start at `b[1]`, you could prepend `0` or some such to the input to `read`, and then `unset "b[0]"` afterwards.

`help read` to get an explanation of the options. Briefly, `-r` avoids interpretation of backslash escape sequences; `-d ''` causes the `read` to terminate at the end of input instead of the end of a line, and `-a b` causes the result to be placed in the array `b`.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
b=($(echo $adse))
```

But it begins with index 0, like:

```
echo ${b[0]}
```

that yields:

```
16.92
```

Answer (score 1):

Although there is an easy solution to achieve what you want, I believe the following is also useful if, say, you have a string whose delimiters are not whitespace:

```
b=()
adse="16.92 18.29 19.18 20.87 2.78 2.88 2.77 2.83 2.80 2.78 2.73 2.73 2.75 2.93 2.91 2.93 2.77 4.64 2.67 3.01 6.78"

b=(${adse// / })
```

For example, if you had a string like this:

```
adse="16.92:18.29...etc"
```

You would have to change `b=(${adse// / })` to:

```
b=(${adse//:/ })
```

However, for your particular case, all that is needed to parse the string into an array is already stated by Birei below.

Comment: That doesn't split on colons; it splits on colons *and* whitespace. It is also way more complicated than is necessary. (And not quoting the variable expansions is asking for trouble. What if they contain glob characters?)